# Interpreting a cubic breezer in my simple CSS-3 animation

Tags: css

Hey guys i have the following Simple CSS-3 transition :

```
@keyframes bounceInLeft {
  0%, 60%, 75%, 90%, 100% {
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(-3000px, 0, 0);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(25px, 0, 0);
  }

  75% {
    transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
  }

  90% {
    transform: translate3d(5px, 0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: none;
  }
}

.bounceInLeft {
  animation-name: bounceInLeft;
}
```

I understand the keyframe animation and that's not a problem , but the part that i find difficult to understand is the cubic-breezer .

I have read some really good articles on cubic breezers one of them being the following ,

[cubic breezer](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/04/15/understanding-css-timing-functions/)

but somehow that seems to be the only CSS-3 property to elude my understanding for such a long time.

can somebody interpret this below line of cubic breezier please :

```
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
```

Heres a fiddle : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3xawfmo/)

Thank you .

Alexander.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be if you play with the effect you can understand it better.

[here](http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/) you can find a nice simulator

For your values, the graphic that you get is this one

The 4 values in your bezier function are the black squares coordinates

[image: graphic demo]

It supports y values outside the 0.1 range

[image]

Comment: so given a cubic breezer (x1 , y1 , y2 , x2) , x1 would be the starting point and x2 the end point of an animation  , suppose any of the two fall outside of the range of [0,1] , suppose x1 is 1.235  , it mean the animation will start with the animated bouncing effect or rather as i have noticed and is common with alot of animations , "Will go outside it's usual animated path" ?? am i right ?

Comment: x values are always in the 0.1 range. It's the y values that can go outside the 0.1 range. (Except in older webkit versions, see the fallbacks in the first line of the images)  And yes, it produces most of the time bouncing effects, see the added example